# Get all children of custom post type using get_pages

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using the `get_pages` function to display all pages within my custom post type, like this:

```
<?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'    => 'pcct_product',
                    'sort_column'  => 'post_title',
                    'menu_order'   => 'ASC'
                );

                $pages = get_pages($args); 
                foreach ( $pages as $pagg ) {
                $option = '<option value="' . get_page_link( $pagg->ID ) . '">';
                $option .= $pagg->post_title;
                $option .= '</option>';
                echo $option;
            }
            ?>
```

I want to be able to display ONLY the children in this custom post type. Has anyone got any suggestions of how I can go about that?

Comment: Do you want to display *all* child pcct_product posts, or only the children of the *current* pcct_product post?

Comment: I want to display _all_ child pcct_products posts

Answer (score 3):

There are a few methods to return all child posts via `get_pages()`.

One fairly straightforward method would be to get all of the IDs of the top-level parent posts, and then pass those IDs to the `exclude` parameter of `get_pages()`:

```
<?php
// Get all top-level pcct_product posts;
// The 'parent' => 0 argument returns only
// posts with a parent ID of 0 - that is, 
// top-level posts
$parent_pcct_products = get_pages( array(
    'post_type'    => 'pcct_product',
    'parent'       => 0
) );
// Create an array to hold their IDs
$parent_pcct_product_ids = array();

// Loop through top-level pcct_product posts, 
// and add their IDs to the array we just
// created.
foreach ( $parent_pcct_products as $parent_pcct_product ) {
    $parent_pcct_product_ids[] = $parent_pcct_product->ID;
}

// Get all child pcct_product posts;
// passing the array of top-level posts
// to the 'exclude' parameter
$child_pcct_products = get_pages( array(
    'post_type'    => 'pcct_product',
    'exclude'      => $parent_pcct_product_ids,
    'hierarchical' => false
) );
?>
```

(Note: untested)

#### Edit

Try setting `hierarchical to`false`, since we're excluding all top-level pages.

Comment: Passing the parent ID's into the exclude parameter removes all of the child pages as well.

Comment: Are you sure about that? It *shouldn't*; that's what the `exclude_tree` parameter is for.

Comment: 100% it is not displaying any child pages. As soon as you exclude the parent page, all the child pages are removed also.

Comment: See updated answer. Try setting `hierarchical` to `false`.

Comment: Bingo! I'll post the updated code as the `get_pages()` parameters also need to be in arrays. I kept getting double arrow errors with the code above. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: #facepalm. I updated the code to wrap `get_pages()` arguments properly within arrays.